# Issues with setting up oauth connecting to MS teams calendar

Tags: microsoft-teams, exchange-server

We have been struggling for a while to setup a connection from on-prem to ms teams for the calendar function. We are not allowed to use classic full hybrid yet so we just want to use the calendar function with oauth. We did all the prerequisites but still have issues.

The mailbox error is because the mailbox is hosted on-prem and cannot be moved to the cloud yet. Oauth should be able to make a connection but it won't work. If we do the inbound to outbound test we get a succesfull answer but from outbound to inbound it wont work.

We have seen similair configuration work in the past even tho microsoft doesn't fully support this option.

They have looked into it but they can't find the issue as well.

When we run the analyser we get this output:

Tried everything, troubleshooting for days with multiple people and also with MS.